# New to Django. How to incorporate "Add more" button in the form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to python and the Django framework. I am dealing with lots of forms in my application which is half way developed by the person working in this position earlier. I now need to change the form to incorporate the "Add additional details" button to my existing form.

Can anyone help me out with this? Do let me know in case you need any additional information from my end.

Comment: Yes I did implement this. Do let me know if you need any help

Comment: Yes,I'm intrested in your solution as I'm trying to do the same,thanks

Comment: Hey I used this plugin....
https://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/ Do let me know if this helps. Good Luck! This works amazingly for me with some twicks as required.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the Forms documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs

I don't really understand what you mean by  "Add additional details". I'm assuming you want to just add additional items to your form.py of your app, be it model data? Again read the doc's they really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form using an (inline) formset?

You need to use javascript or jQuery to insert a new set of fields into the web page. The formset management values need to be updated as well.

See [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/) or [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/)

Comment: @Glyn Jackson it is like I have a form with the fields from multiple models and  and I need one field to be added as many number of times as user needs by providing him a small + button (which means add more). Thus I need the help in developing this dynamic kind of form. I am pretty new to Django.